# How to display record by ID (primarykey) in database to view automatically or dynamically in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have no MVC data for this question, but you can help me by other example

Comment: what actually u need,

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your controller as Demo.php:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Demo extends CI_Controller    {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    $this->load->model('demo_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    function display_content()
    {
        $data   = array();            
        $data['result'] = $this->demo_model->get_records();
        $this->load->view('demo/show_content', $data);
    }
}
```

Your model as demo_model.php :

```
    class demo_model extends CI_Model
 {
    function get_records()
    {
        $this->db->select('your tbl columns'); //Ex: u_id,fname,lname
        $this->db->from('your tbl name'); // tbl_user
        $this->db->order_by("title", "desc"); //u_id
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result();
    }
}
```

Your view file as show_content.php :

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>All Records</th>

</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $res): ?>
<tr><?php echo $res->content; ?></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
?>
```

This is sample, now you have to set-up all parameters as per your need...

Comment: Thanks @kunal I will try this